# Selenium Webdriver JS Scraping Parallely [nodejs]

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to create a pool of Phantom Webdrivers [using webdriverjs] like

```
var driver = new Webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(Webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs()).build();
```

Once the pool gets populated [I see n-number of phantom processes spawned], I try to do `driver.get` [using different drivers in the pool] of different urls expecting them to work parallely [as driver.get is async].

But I always see them being done sequentially. 
Can't we load different urls parallely via different web driver instances? 
If not possible in this way how else could I solve this issue?

Very Basic Impl of my question would look like below

```
var Webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),

function getInstance() {
   return new Webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(Webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs()).build();
}

var pool = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  pool.push(getInstance());
}
pool[0].get("http://mashable.com/2014/01/14/outdated-web-features/").then(function () { 
  console.log(0);
});

pool[1].get("http://google.com").then(function () { 
  console.log(1);
});

pool[2].get("http://techcrunch.com").then(function () { 
  console.log(2);
});
```

PS: Have already posted it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/S7hmlDx2CF8)

Update:
I tried with selenium grid with the following setup; as it was mentioned that it can run tests parallely

Hub:

```
java -jar selenium/selenium-server-standale-2.39.0.jar -hosost 127.0.0.1 -port 4444 -role hub -nodeTimeout 600
```

Phantom:

```
phantomjs --webdriver=7777 --webdriver-selium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444 --debug=true
phantomjs --webdriver=7877 --webdriver-selium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444 --debug=true
phantomjs --webdriver=6777 --webdriver-selium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444 --debug=true
```

Still I see the `get` command getting queued and executed sequentially instead being parall. [But gets properly distributed across 3 instances]

Am I still missing something out?

Why is it mentioned "scale by distributing tests on several machines ( **parallel execution** )" in the doc?

What is parallel as per the hub? I'm getting clueless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I got the issue..

Basically https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/executors.js#39 Is synchronous and blocking operation [atleast the get].
Whenever the *get* command is issued node's main thread get's stuck there. No further code execution.

Comment: So what was your solution exactly ? I am facing similar issues and running out of ideas

Comment: The issue is in the selenium hub end [even if u use the grid same issue].. So, one possible solution could be to use multiple hubs.

Comment: Multiple hubs did not work. See my answer for a solution though.

Comment: Yeah I agree with multiple hubs we got to do with cluster type of setup.. Coz at the end of the day node thread is blocked if we are using single node instance

Answer (score 1):

A little late but for me it worked with webdriver.promise.createFlow.
You just have to wrap your code in webdriver.promise.createFlow() { ... }); and it works for me! Here's an example from [Make parallel requests to a Selenium Webdriver grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701648/make-parallel-requests-to-a-selenium-webdriver-grid). All thanks to the answerer there...

```
var flows = [0,1,2,3].map(function(index) {
 return webdriver.promise.createFlow(function() {
   var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').usingServer('http://someurl:44111/wd/hub/').build();

   console.log('Get');
   driver.get('http://www.somepage.com').then(function() {

        console.log('Screenshot');
        driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data){

            console.log('foo/test' + index + '.png');
            //var decodedImage = new Buffer(data, 'base64')

            driver.quit();
        });
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, I finally got around the problem using [**child_process**](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

The way my app is setup is that I have many tasks that does different things, and that needs to run simultaneously *(each of those use a different driver instance)*, obviously it was not working. 
I now start those tasks in a **child_process** *(which will run a new V8 process)* and **it does run everything in parallel.**